# Python "'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, module, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot:

```
from matplotlib import *
import sys
from pylab import *

f = figure ( figsize =(7,7) )
```

But I get this error when I try to execute it:

```
  File "mratio.py", line 24, in <module>
    f = figure( figsize=(7,7) )
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have run a similar script before, and I think I've imported all the relevant modules.

Comment: have you shadowed `figure` with something else?

Comment: run `import pylab; print pylab.__file__` and give us the result

Comment: /home/apps/fas/Langs/Python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.pyc

Comment: How about `print pylab.figure`?

Comment: Also what are the conents of "/home/apps/fas/Langs/Python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.p‌​y"?

Comment: `print pylab.figure` gives `<function figure at 0xd575410>`

Comment: "/home/apps/fas/Langs/Python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.‌​p‌​y" exists and seems normal. This is strange since I've been able to use this function before.

Comment: I see your error is on line 24, do you actually get this error when your run your snippet, or only something longer?

Comment: I haven't tried just running the snippet. But I found that once I import a bunch of seemingly unrelated modules, it starts to work again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `figure` is a module provided by `matplotlib`.

You can read more about it in the [Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html)

I think what you want is `matplotlib.figure.Figure` (the class, rather than the module)

It's [documented here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure)

```
from matplotlib import *
import sys
from pylab import *

f = figure.Figure( figsize =(7,7) )
```

or

```
from matplotlib import figure
f = figure.Figure( figsize =(7,7) )
```

or

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
f = Figure( figsize =(7,7) )
```

or to get `pylab` to work without conflicting with `matplotlib`:

```
from matplotlib import *
import sys
import pylab as pl

f = pl.figure( figsize =(7,7) )
```

Comment: But `figure` should be a function from `pylab` and so this should still work.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I've added another solution to allow `pylab` to import figure without conflicting with `matplotlib`

Comment: But that doesn't explain why `figure` from `pylab` didn't replace `matplotlib`'s figure. It should have.

Comment: I was wondering the same. I've plotted figures before without calling "figure.Figure".

Comment: Using the code snippet on it's own works with Python v3.5, however if I change the import order, loading pylab before matplotlib, I get the error. So the order is important. Best to explicitly specify `pl.figure` as suggested by @Ewan to avoid this

Comment: see @minion_1 for the 2020 solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
matplotlib.figure.Figure
```

Here,

```
matplotlib.figure is a package (module), and `Figure` is the method
```

Reference [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure).

So you would have to call it like this:

```
f = figure.Figure(figsize=(7,7))
```

Comment: The solution of @minion_1 is the actual solution, this here is 2013 solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
from matplotlib import *
```

use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: This has been stated before by minion_1. Still you offer a clearly formatted advice for the change.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent future errors regarding matplotlib.pyplot, try doing this: 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

If you use Jupyter notebooks and use: %matplotlib inline, make sure that the "%matplotlib inline FOLLOWS the import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Karthikr's answer works but might not eliminate errors in other lines of code related to the pyplot module.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter notebook I solved this issue by importig matplotlib.pyplot instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
```

Making plots with `f = plt.figure()` now works.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Library:

```
import matplotlib as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
```

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

But

Correct Library:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
```

Above code worked for me for the same error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).