# TypeError when importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I am importing matplotlib the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then when I execute the command:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why it could be happening, as I always import pyplot like that and I never have any issues.

When printing plt I obtain the following:

```
<module 'matplotlib' from 'C:\\Users\\itsas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.py'>
```

When I substitute all my 'plt' for 'matplotlib.pyplot', it works...
It's almost as if it wasn't importing pyplot for some reason...

Comment: Try printing 'plt' and add the output to your question.

Comment: just have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527149/python-module-object-is-not-callable ,you will get your answer

Comment: I included what happens when I print plt!

Comment: what did `import pylab; print pylab.__file__` return ?

Comment: C:\Users\itsas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pylab.py

Comment: You very probably assigned `plt.figure = ...` either somewhere earlier in your code, or in an interactive environment.  Try restarting your environment.